# Easiest way to receive UDP packets?

Tags: python, c++, udp

What is the easiest way to receive UDP packets knowing the address and port it is sent to ?

To add a little bit of context : the UDP data stream comes from a game that requires me to enter the address and port to send it to.

I don't need to send anything back, I just need to receive the data so I can use it in a Python or C++ program.
Therefore Python and C++ solutions would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose i would recommend using python. It is much simpler to set up and dont require compiling so you can easier fool around with your UDP data.

I appended a crude example for a UDP receiver.
You just have to figure out how to process your received data to your needs.

```
# run with python3

import socketserver  # we use the socketsever module that comes with python3

class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.DatagramRequestHandler):

def handle(self):
    print("Got an UDP Message from {}".format(self.client_address[0]))

    # for line terminated massages
    msgRecvd = self.rfile.readline().strip()
    print("The Message is {}".format(msgRecvd))

    # with receive buffer - reads max 1024 bytes
    # rec_bytes = self.request.recv(1024)
    # your processing here

# this is the main entrypoint
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # we specify the address and port we want to listen on
    listen_addr = ('0.0.0.0', 5099)

    # with allowing to reuse the address we dont get into problems running it consecutively sometimes
    socketserver.UDPServer.allow_reuse_address = True 

    # register our class
    serverUDP = socketserver.UDPServer(listen_addr, MyUDPHandler)
    serverUDP.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a server program and bind on a certain port. The game then will act as a client to this server and when you enter the address and the port that your server binded to, you will receive the messages in the code.

You can check this link for the server code in C++: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/

You can search also for how to create a udp server socket in Python.